# Are compiler-generated assignment operators unsafe?

Tags: c++

It was my understanding that the C++ compiler generates assignment operators like this:

```
struct X {
    std::vector<int> member1;
    std::vector<int> member2;
    X& operator=(const X& other) {
        member1 = other.member1;
        member2 = other.member2;
    }
};
```

Isn't this exception-unsafe? If `member2 = other.member2` throws, then the original assignment's side effects are not undone.

Comment: It doesn't provide the strong exception guarantee. That's not the same thing as not begin safe. There will be no memory leaks or anything like that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I think that not providing the strong guarantee *is* inherently unsafe, in general, and certainly should merit special consideration from the programmer where non-strong functions are concerned.

Comment: Hmm... what are the guarantees from the standard concerning partial assignment?

Comment: @DeadMG: Then you have your answer, no? But you should probably clarify in your question exactly what "exception-unsafe" means to you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Is it "are assignment operators generated like this?", or is it "I know assignment operators are generated like this; does this allow an exception to leave an object half-assigned?", or is it "I know assignment operators are generated like this, and that this allows an exception to leave an object half-assigned; is that considered exception-unsafe?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [4 level exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) system:

- No throw
- Strong Guarantee -- operation completes, or is rolled back completely
- Basic Guarantee -- invariants are preserved, no resources leaked
- No Guarantees

The compiler generated assignment operator has the basic exception guarantee if each of the members of the object provides the basic exception guarantee or "better", and if the objects invariants do not have intra-member dependencies.

It has the no throw guarantee if each member's assignment also has the no throw guarantee.

It rarely (if ever) has the strong guarantee, which is possibly what you are referring to as "exception unsafe".

The copy-swap idiom is popular because writing no-throw `swap` is often easy, and constructors should already provide the strong exception guarantee.  The result is an `operator=` with the strong exception guarantee.  (In the case of `move`, it is pseudo-strong, as the input is often not rolled back, but it is an rvalue)

```
void swap( Foo& other ) noexcept; // implement this
Foo& operator=( Foo const& f ) {
  Foo tmp(f);
  swap( tmp );
  return *this;
}
Foo& operator=( Foo && f ) {
  Foo tmp(std::move(f));
  swap( tmp );
  return *this;
}
```

If you also take the copy by-value, you can sometimes upgrade `operator=` to being no throw (with the only exception being possibly in the construction of the argument).

```
Foo& operator=( Foo f ) noexcept {
  swap( f );
  return *this;
}
```

in some cases, some constructors of `Foo` are `noexcept` and others are not: by taking the other by-value, we provide the best exception guarantee we can in total (as the argument to `=` can sometimes be directly constructed, either by elision or direct construction via `{}`).

It is not practical for the language (at least at this time) to implement a copy-swap `operator=` with the strong guarantee for a few reasons.  First, C++ operates on "you only pay for what you use", and copy-swap can be more expensive than memberwise copy.  Second, `swap` is not currently part of the core language (there are some proposals to add `operator :=:` and fold it in).  Third, reverse compatibility with previous versions of C++ and with C.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited 4 June 2014**

My initial answer was based on my understanding that the original poster sought an assignment operator guaranteed not to throw an exception.  As per various commenters, it has become apparent that exceptions are OK as long as the object is left un-altered on an exception.

The suggested way to do this is via temp variables and std::swap().

```
X& X::operator=(const X& other)
{
    // assign to temps.  If this throws, the object
    // has not changed.
    auto m1 = other.member1;
    auto m2 = other.member2;

    // the theory is, that swap won't throw
    // can we rely on that?
    std::swap(m1, member1);
    std::swap(m2, member2);

    return *this;
}
```

In fact we cannot rely that swap() won't throw an exception, unless we know a bit about the components of our object.

To be sure that swap() will never throw, we need the member objects to be [Move Assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) and [Move Constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible).

In the example given, with a C++11 or later compiler the std::vector<int> *is* 
move assignable and move constructible, so we are safe.  However as a general solution we always need to be aware of any assumptions we are making and to check that they are holding.

Comment: I would expect it to not catch the exception, but rather copy 1 to 2 temps, if that works then swap them (which won't throw). If the copying throws the object is left unchanged.

Comment: If the members are POD (plain old data) then no exception will be thrown and everything is safe.  If the members can throw exceptions, then that means that the assignment can fail.  Even if you mess 'round with temps and swap() you might still fail.  What do you do then?

Comment: @MichaelJ If you use temporaries, and it fails during the construction of the temporary, your own instance won't have been modified yet. So, you do nothing. The caller can catch the exception if appropriate, or not. Either way, it's not your problem. If it fails during the swap between your own instance and that temporary, you've got a poorly-defined swap, because that should pretty much never need to throw, and in that case, fix the swap function.

Comment: swap from the temps should never throw, or fail! It should boil down to re-assigning pointers

Comment: Your answer seems to be guided by the idea that the goal is for the assignment operator to not throw exceptions. But that is not the point. Your solution (which is a terrible idea, imo) doesn't even guarantee that anyway, since exceptions do not necessarily derive from `std::exception` (though they should). The goal is that if an exception *is* thrown, it is guaranteed that the object is left unmodified.

Comment: +1 now that the code has a strong guarantee, PS std::swap will never throw as its essentially moving bits of stack around, that can't fail unless you throw a grenade in your computer or something